# Javascript syntax: Function insideof a For loop

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop

Syntax issue here as the code works fine.
I have a for loop and an inline function that must run within it (aQuery callback).

```
  for (i=1;i <= 5;i++)  
            {
            twitter[i] = $(this).find('twitter' + i).text();
            //$('<div class="twitter[i]"></div>').html(twitter[i]).appendTo('#link_'+i);
            $('.twitter[i]').html(twitter[i]).appendTo('#link_'+i);

            // grab from twitter
            $.getJSON('http://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.json?screen_name='+twitter[i]+'&callback=?', 

            function (data)     
                    {
                          for (j=1;j <= 5; j++)     {
                          twit_count[j] = data['followers_count'].toString();
                          twit_count[j] = add_commas(twit_count[j]);
                          $('#twitter_count'+j).html(twit_count[j]);
                          }
                    }); 
             }
```

If i=3 I want j to be the same value within the function.

The problem is the j loop runs five times for every i loop.

Passing i as an argument

```
 function (data, i)
```

doesn't work, some direction would be highly appreciated.

**Thanks,**

Comment: If the value of i = 1, you want the j loop to run once, twice for i = 2, thrice for i = 3.... Is that what you need?

Comment: yes it is ^^ how do I do that?

Comment: Then just replace for (j=1;j <= 5; j++) with for (j=1;j <= i; j++)

Comment: thanks Nikhil that solved another of my problems.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure what you want, but if you want to have the callback function just do one set of counters, it shouldn't have a loop in it.

To get the value of j inside the callback to have the same value as i, you have to write a function to return the callback function, and pass the desired value as an argument to the outer function.

```
$.getJSON(url, ( function(j) { 
      return function(data) { 
          twit_count[j] = data['followers_count'].toString();
          twit_count[j] = add_commas(twit_count[j]);
        $('#twitter_count'+j).html(twit_count[j]);
      }
   } )(i) )
```

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10844048/why-does-dynamically-adding-onclick-to-an-img-element-when-in-a-loop-require/10844085#10844085) for more explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Hi guys just to answer my own question.

I wanted a list of Facebook/Twitter followers per page.

```
var f_page = ["TheHouseofMarley, Another FB ID, Another FB ID, Another FB ID"];

    for(var i=0; i < 1; i++) 
                    {
                        retrieveData(f_page[i]);
                    }

    function retrieveData(teamName) {

    var baseURL = 'http://graph.facebook.com/';
    $.getJSON(baseURL+teamName+"&callback=?", function(data) {
    $('#FBlikes').append(teamname ":" data.likes)
        });
    };
```

Then in < body >

```
<span id='FBlikes'></span>
```